# Declaring mapped address as an extern

Tags: c, embedded, mapping, extern

I'm trying to map some locations, and here is a sample of my code. The point I want to declare porta and ddra as an extern variables so I can share them between files.

```
typedef union _porta
{
  byte REGISTER;
  struct 
  {
     unsigned PA0:1;
     unsigned PA1:1;
     unsigned PA2:1;
     unsigned PA3:1;
     unsigned PA4:1;
     unsigned PA5:1;
     unsigned PA6:1;
     unsigned PA7:1;

  };
}PORTA;


typedef union _da
{
  byte REGISTER;
  struct 
  {
     unsigned  DA0:1;
     unsigned  DA1:1;
     unsigned  DA2:1;
     unsigned  DA3:1;
     unsigned  DA4:1;
     unsigned  DA5:1;
     unsigned  DA6:1;
     unsigned  DA7:1;

  };
}DDRA;


#define porta      (*(( volatile PORTA *)0x22))
#define  ddra        ( *(( volatile DDRA *)0x21) ) 
// Here in the same header want to declare porta and ddra as an extern variables I can use outside
```

Comment: Any reason why you are hacking your own register map with bit-fields? The most common reason for making your own register map is that the default one is useless because of bit-fields. If bit-fields are acceptable to you (no requirements about portability between compilers) then simply use the register map provided by Atmel or Freescale (this smells like either AVR or HC08/HC12).

Comment: `porta` and `ddra` are macros not variables - you cannot declare a macro `extern`, and neither do you need to.  The macros refer to constant expressions that will be evaluated at compile time and inlined   where the macros are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple put the defines and the typedefs in a header file and name it "xxx_registers.h" or some such (where xxx is your MCU). That's how this is usually done.

However, you should name the typedef `DDRA_t` and then `#define DDRA ... volatile DDRA_t*`. It is custom to always use capital letters for register names.

IMPORTANT: Make sure that strict aliasing is disabled in your compiler! Otherwise code like this may break in horrible ways. This is mostly a problem with the gcc compiler, but other compilers might handle strict aliasing in similar dysfunctional ways. For gcc, always compile with `-fno-strict-aliasing` when coding embedded systems, or otherwise that compiler can't be used.

Please note that bit-fields are non-portable and dangerous, so there is no guarantee that this code will work on other compilers. It is better and safer to use bitwise operators for accessing individual bits, rather than bit-fields.

Comment: Thank you , It helped me much.

Comment: This is helpful, but can you clarify the last part: I am presuming disabling strict aliasing needs to be done because the writers of libraries for these MCU's register libraries don't really care about the C standard? Or is there some other fundamental reason why GCC is problematic?

Comment: @Groo When programming embedded systems - or anything else close to the hardware - you often need to do things like "write a word" or "this register can be used either as one 32 bit register or two 16 bit registers". Such common and perfectly valid scenarios collide with the strict aliasing rule. Before gcc went C standard fundamentalists, this was not a problem - all compilers allow a pointer-to-word to access the underlying memory, even if there happens to be other variables allocated there. All embedded compilers except gcc does this. ->

Comment: But with gcc becoming popular for embedded systems, there's been a flood of strict aliasing-related bugs in such hardware-related code. Therefore strict aliasing must always be disabled when using gcc for embedded systems, or that compiler can't be used. The alternative would be to write all sensitive parts in inline assembler, which is not a nice option. The root of the problem is however the C standard itself - the strict aliasing rule is badly phrased and needs to be remade.

Comment: @Lundin: thanks, we do low level embedded programming in our company, we were until recently stuck on a certain compiler by Tasking which was a story of its own, but didn't experience these problems. Now that we've recently switched to the ARM platform which uses gcc in its toolset, this is very helpful to know.

Comment: @Groo For gcc bare metall embedded applications, make sure to use `-ffreestanding -std=cxx -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -fno-strict-aliasing`.